# How to automatically generate multiple aliases for one node?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm using Drupal 7.22. I'm running four site versions in same Drupal installation.

eg:-

- example.com/site1
- example.com/site1

and its mobile versions:

- example.com/mobilesite1
- example.com/mobilesite2

I'm using URL aliases to meet the conditions. I have created patterns for each content type.
Suppose I have content type called `site1_projects` and  `site2_projects`, and created aliases for each site content type like `site1/site1_projects` and `site2/site2_projects`.

How can I automatically set an aliasing for these content type for mobile, like `mobilesite1/site1_projects` and `mobilesite2/site2_projects`?

Comment: It was [discussed on drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/457842) - go and see, and if you'll find an answer there don't be shy to post it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In canse you didnt found it, you need to use the module ***Rules*** and follow these steps:

```
**Delete Node Aliases Ruleset**
- Delete all aliases that point to system path
- Delete all aliases that point to system path
- ... (and so forth)

**Create Node Aliases Ruleset**
- Create alias #1 to point to path A
- Create alias #2 to point to path B
- ... (and so forth)

**Triggered Rules**
- IF new node created (and any other conditions) THEN call Create Node Aliases ruleset.
- IF node deleted (...) THEN call Delete Node Aliases ruleset.
- IF node updated (...) THEN call Delete Node Aliases and then call Create Node Aliases
```