# Creating multiple URL aliases for the same node with their own context

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri

I want to solve the following problem with Drupal 7 solely using existing modules and without any extra code.

- I have a contenttype called 'News'
- I create a news item and assign a taxonomy term called 'Sport' and a taxonomy term called 'Entertainment'.

---

- Now I want Drupal to create two URL aliases, namely:

  - http://www.domain.com/news/sport/title
  - http://www.domain.com/entertainment/title
- I want to assign different blocks based on the path with context.

Is this possible without custom code? And if custom code is neccesary how would I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

This should be working using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) modules. There's already a similar question that is answered: [How to automatically generate multiple aliases for one node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76118/how-to-automatically-generate-multiple-aliases-for-one-node?rq=1)

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate? I've created a rule after saving a new node which has two actions: creating two aliases http://www.domain.com/news/sport/title and http://www.domain.com/entertainment/title.

But it seems the second alias overrules the first so the node is only accesible through http://www.domain.com/entertainment/title.

Comment: What you describe sounds like you are possibly using the global redirect module? Have you tried to create some url-aliases manually for testing (you can do that under -> admin/config/search/path/add)?