# How do I create a ruleset component?

Tags: 8, rules, plugins

I would like to create a custom ruleset component like the one described in  [How to automatically generate multiple aliases for one node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/76118/how-to-automatically-generate-multiple-aliases-for-one-node)

That answer is for Drupal 7, and I am using Drupal 8. When I go to Rules/Components, none of the plugin options that I see in screenshots of Drupal 7 appear to be available (e.g. rule set, condition set, action set). Basically, the *Components* tab looks nothing like the one found in Drupal 7, so it's unclear to me how to create a ruleset. I'm not a module developer, but when I look through the module folder, I see a folder named Plugins/RulesExpression which contains files that seem to correspond to these component plugin types. Is there something I have to do to enable them to be available in the administration pages?

The documentation for Drupal 8 [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) is basically empty. The only documentation I found is for contributing developers; it doesn't seem there is any updated documentation for administrator users of the module, and I have searched far and wide for any insight on this and found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While Rules components may successfully be created and used programmatically, as of Rules 8.x-3.0-alpha4 there is only minimal support for doing this in the UI. Adding these UI features is part of the last meta task needed to be completed before a beta version of Rules is released. You can discover the current status of these UI porting issues by reading the Rules issue queue at https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/rules